# Django link text too long

Tags: html, django, hyperlink

In my detail view in my Django app I show links to all attached files in the Post. Problem is, if link is too long it goes beyond border. Is it possible to show only part of link if it's too long or to limit the 'preview', not to edit the link.

[image]

code:

```
{% for i in post.file_set.all %}<p class="article-content mt-2 mb-1"><strong>Privitak prijave {{ forloop.counter }}: </strong><a href="{{i.file.url}}">{{i.file.name}}</a></p>{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [**`|truncatechars`** template filter <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#truncatechars):

```
{{ i.file.name|truncatechars:20 }}
```